# How might a Kardashev Scale Level II civilization transport energy?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, energy

We all know the [Kardashev Scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kardashev_scale) , and the energy output required to get to each level , but what would be the best way to transport those amounts of energy? I have come up with ways to distribute energy on the second level of the scale , and would like to know which of each set would be most feasible ( which would result in the least amount of energy loss )

**LEVEL II**

- laser beams ( turn the energy into light and shining them into black gas to convert it into heat energy , which then can be converted into any energy of the recipient's choosing )
- Plasma cartridges ( use the energy to super heat a noble gas ,store it in a magnetic field , send it into orbit around a black-hole, planet, or star, and use the gravity to fling it to its destination )
- Tesla coil planet ( turn the energy into electricity and placing it into a dwarf planet sized Tesla Coil , sending the electricity to artificial satellites that would also act as tesla coils , the from there, the electricity would be send to that planets inhabitants )

Any and all feedback is appreciated as always, 
Thanks

Comment: Someone , please show me how to delete this

Comment: At the bottom, below the tags, there is a delete button. Also, if someone knew, we would probably be along the lines of a level II.

Comment: You cannot delete your question because it has an upvoted, accepted answer. [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/157730) In principle in a situation like this you could flag for moderator attention and request deletion, but in general, moderators are very reluctant to allow you to delete a post that you couldn't otherwise delete yourself, because someone (in this case, Henry Taylor) has spent time composing a useful answer, so the flag would likely be declined.

Comment: Fair enough @ Micheal Kjörling

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Will we continue to store energy, or will that idea go out of style once we figure out how to ignite fusion on demand?  Level II implies that we master and consume energy equivalent to the output of our own sun.  It does not require that that energy actually come from our sun.

I imagine every citizen of level II civilization will have a matchbox sized object in their pocket in which a perfectly safe and controlled fusion reaction can ignite upon demand.  Containing several years of fuel, these matchboxes can provide their users with enormous power as needed; and larger units are available for projects which exceed the matchbox's capacity.

In other words, we won't store and transport energy anymore.  We'll just create it on the spot and in the moment that we need it.

Comment: "In other words, we won't store and transport energy anymore."  Or to be more accurate, energy will be stored and transported as inert mass.

Comment: Your answer basically says we *will* continue to store and transport energy, we just won't need to do so as chemical or electrical energy.  Instead we'll store it as fusion fuel.  The good news is this is perhaps 10,000,000 x more dense than chemical energy storage.

Comment: Both of you are correct.  If I added that the matchbox can harvest new fuel  like Dr. Brown's Mr. Fusion, would that make my conclusion more appropriate or do banana peels and aluminum cans count as stored energy?